# C# User Control - Accessing control properties from within user control

Tags: c#, telerik

I am building a series of user controls and when I put a third party control on the form (Telerik RadGridview) I cannot access it's properties. If I place a TextBox on the control I can access it's properties fine.

Any reason why this would be the case?
How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the property from?  Also, please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the third-party control is properly registered either in your Web.Config or using the @Register declaration inside of your user control.  Here is an example of the web.config entry:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="CTRL" assembly="MyCustomControlsAssemblyName" namespace="MyCustomControls.SomeNamespace" />
</controls>
```